# SQL SELECT make response contain only value and not column name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this SQL Query to get all users registered device token:

```
select distinct device_token 
from users 
where device_token is not null
```

This returns an array:

```
[
    { "device_token": "LONG SRING 1" },
    { "device_token": "LONG SRING 2" },
    { "device_token": "LONG SRING 3" }
]
```

How can I make this response look like this?

```
[
    "LONG SRING 1",
    "LONG SRING 2",
    "LONG SRING 3"
]
```

I print out my array like this just to compare:

```
print_r($response);
print_r(array_values($response));
```

It prints:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [device_token] => LONG STRING 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [device_token] => LONG STRING 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [device_token] => LONG STRING 3
    )
)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [device_token] => LONG STRING 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [device_token] => LONG STRING 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [device_token] => LONG STRING 3
    )
)
```

array_values() doesn't change anything :(

Comment: What you're getting is a json string. Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse it.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I encoded it into json just for this question for easier readability. Otherwise its still the same PHP array structure...

Comment: Take a look at `REPLACE`.

Comment: If it's a PHP array then check the list of PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php). In particular, [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) could be the function you need.

Answer (score 3):

Use array_value to get only value from an associative array

```
array_values($array);
```

Comment: Doesnt work, nothing changes. Could it be because the array I receive from my database server is 2 stages deep?

Comment: paste your array here

Comment: Updated my question, thanks for your will to help me.

Comment: its a multidimensional array object , array_value cant work in this situation

Comment: Yes thats what I was thinking, I have to loop through it and extract the values manually?

Answer (score 0):

You have do it manually by using loop..

```
$json = '[{"device_token":"LONG SRING 1"},{"device_token":"LONG SRING 2"},{"device_token":"LONG SRING 3"}]';
    $json = json_decode($json, true);
    $result = array();
    foreach($json as $row){
        $result[] = $row['device_token'];
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
```

now you will get response in this format...

```
["LONG SRING 1","LONG SRING 2","LONG SRING 3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing like this:

```
if (PF::is_multi($token)) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach (array_values($token) as $value)
        array_push($temp, array_values($value)[0]);
    $token = $temp;
}
```